# When package dependant libraries in the "lib" folder of the hadoop job jar, ClassNotFoundException encountered

Tags: hadoop, classnotfoundexception

I used to package the dependent libraries in the "lib" folder of the Hadoop map-reduce job jar. That works fine. But this time it went wrong. Can some one give me some idea to fix the problem? The problem is as follows:

When I package the job jar with Eclipse "Export" function and "Extract required libraries into generated JAR" option. The generated job jar works fine.

But if I package the job jar with ant-script to include dependent libraries in the "lib" folder in the job jar, I encountered the ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.io.IOException: Split class cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputSplit not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:365)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:325)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cascading.tap.hadoop.MultiInputSplit
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:943)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:338)
        ... 7 more
```

Can anyone provide some idea?

Comment: And you're absolutely sure the jar contains the dependent jar in a lib folder - does jar -tvf myJar.jar confrm this?

Comment: extract both the jars: one created by eclipse and other created by ant,...do you see any differences ? I am guessing that there might be something missing in the ant file which might be causing this.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure the class is there. It is an cascading class. I have checked many times. Even I unpack the cascading class files in the ant generated job jar. Still the problem.

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/ Just try this.

Comment: Did you use Job.setJarByClass?

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) would resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Jars are zip files under the cover.
Thus, why don't you

- rename both jars to zips
- extract them
- use file/folder compare tools to compare both extracted folders (Beyond Compare, WinMerge, etc)

The difference could be in manifest as well.

After you know what the difference is, it would be easier to configure your build tools to generate the correct jar files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cascading, then make sure that the JAR that contains the class you set in

```
_props = new Properties();
AppProps.setApplicationJarClass(_props, MyMain.class);
```

is the JAR that has 'lib' folder with all dependencies.

Sometimes, what happens is the JAR (lets call it MyWorkflow.jar) that contains MyMain.class is in its own jar *without lib folder* and there is another 'module' that does ten different things apart from invoking cascading workflow. This master module (lets call this MasterModule.jar) has MyWorkflow module defined as a maven dependency. So when one tries to run

```
hadoop jar MasterModule.jar <options>
```

one would expect all jars in MasterModule.jar lib folder to be added to TaskTracker's classpath... but Cascading finds that MyMain.class belongs to MyWorkflow.jar & does not see any lib folder in MyWorkflow.jar so you start seeing ClassNotFoundException...!

Also note that lib folder dependencies will not be supported from CDH5. 
[Cloudera Blog](http://*Update%20to%20post:%20Please%20note%20that%20items%202%20and%203%20below%20are%20deprecated%20starting%20CDH4%20and%20will%20be%20no%20longer%20supported%20starting%20CDH5.)